# Allow a user to override a default action via an event (eg use of e.handled or e.cancel = true or false)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, events, event-handling, custom-controls

I have a WPF Custom control which I have been building as I happen to need a particular functionality and I want to learn how to do this properly.  Most of the control has now come together nicely and is generally pretty usable.  There is now one feature that I'd like to implement, however, I'm not sure if it's possible in the first place or if it is how I would or should go about implementing it.

So here goes by way of my explanation of what I have and what I would like.  Feel free to ask for extra clarification if required.

My control raises a custom event which passes along some custom event args.  The event is declared like so in the control.

```
Public Event RecordControlButtonClicked(sender As Object, e As VtlDataNavigatorEventArgs)
```

In most cases when this event is raised the end user has simply clicked the button, nothing other than raising the event will take place because the developer using the control will most likely want to decide how they handle the situation at that particular moment and the custom event args provide more than enough info to do that.

There are however a couple of buttons where in all honesty the developer will probably want to happen what I (as the developer of the control) envisage should happen most of the time but on the odd occasion might not and therefore needs the opportunity to cancel out of it. So what I'm wondering is how I might achieve the following:

1. The end user clicks a button
2. The control button raises my custom event
3. The developer using my custom controls decides they wish to ignore what I (the creator of the control) thinks should happen, so they do something like e.handled = true in the code where they handle my custom event.
4. Somehow that message gets back to the button that raised the event, it seems that it's been 'handled' or 'canceled' and as a result does nothing

My question is how do I create that sort of functionality and is the event that I currently have declared the correct sort of event to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Well just in case anyone stumbles across this looking for an answer.

It transpires that my basic mistake lay in the way that I'd Created my custom events class.  Originally I'd followed several examples that I'd read about and had my custom events inherit from EventArgs;

```
  Public Class MyCustomEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs

  End Class
```

What I should have done was have it inherit from CancelEventArgs;

```
Public Class MyCustomEventArgs
    Inherits System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs

  End Class
```

That provides the Property that I was after.  Now when the event is actually handled upstreap the developer can add an e.cancel = true and all I need to do back in the originating call to raise the event is listen out for e.cancel ;

```
RaiseEvent MyCustomEvent(sender, e)
if e.cancel = true
    'presumably don't do something
Else
   'do what needs to be done
End If
```